# Formating txt file and displaying it to gridview

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

this is my first post, and I am new to C# so please be gentle :P. 
I am writing application that is reading some txt files and then displaying them in gridview (I am later doing some more things with it, but it is not important right now). Almost all of my files have some established system of characters (there are always three columns that are separated with coma) and here I have no problem with reading them putting in list and then bind into gridview. 
But I also have some files that don't have same system of characters, and I have problem with dealing with them. Can You help me to somehow format them to this original system of characters (I mean this one with commas). Bellow is my function for loading everything into list and then into gridview. I also posted example of file with good system of characters, and this one which is not formated.

29-01-2013 03:49:31.629,Some text ghs(23).asv[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fW0c.png), more text

17-07-2011 12:12:32.643,Some text also dsad(1), more text

31-01-2013 08:14:08.473,Some text sdfsdfsd[2], more text

Not formated text has some spaces at the beggining, then some number, (dot), and another space. After this I would like to start reading and get rid of everything that was before. Moreover between my proper data it does not have commas but spaces. It is sth like this.

Please guys can You help me??

1. 23-05-2009 12:12:45.675  Some text fsdf[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fW0c.png)  some more text
2. 13-02-2003 11:12:45.454  Some text sdfsdfS(1)  some more text

   ```
       private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       List<MyColumns> list = new List<MyColumns>();

       OpenFileDialog openFile1 = new OpenFileDialog();
       openFile1.Multiselect = true;

       if (openFile1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
       {
           foreach (string filename in openFile1.FileNames)
           {

               using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
               {
                   string line;
                   while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                   {
                       string[] _columns = line.Split(",".ToCharArray());
                       MyColumns mc = new MyColumns();
                       mc.Time = _columns[0];
                       mc.System_Description = _columns[1];
                       mc.User_Description = _columns[2];
                       list.Add(mc);
                   }
               }
           }
           DataTable ListAsDataTable = BuildDataTable<MyColumns>(list);
           DataView ListAsDataView = ListAsDataTable.DefaultView;
           this.dataGridView1.DataSource = view = ListAsDataView;
           this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
           dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
       }
       textBox1.Text = this.dataGridView1.Rows.Count.ToString();
   }
   ```

   I was thinking also about using reg expresions, format of my text would look like this. Field1>(6)Field2>(23)Field3>(2)Field4>(50+)  field 3 are spaces that work as delimiters, is it possible to change them to commas, while working with text??

Comment: Its hard to offer advice with out an example of the data you want formatted. The first thing I would do is remove all the white space. What is the delimiter in the 'un-formatted' files.

Comment: It looks like in the example above. It starts with few spaces then I have number with '.' after it, then 2 more spaces and finally data that I am interested in. Delimeter in this case are 2 spaces.

Comment: The first section would be easy to delimit, look for the second space from the left and break at that position, but breaking the second and third columns apart is pretty much impossible, unless the second column is always guaranteed to end in a number (potentially followed by parenthesis or square brackets).

Comment: Ok, but how should I perform this task? How can I get rid of this parts of text. While searching for this second space I should also use normal split option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is fixed-width columns, then one way would be using string.Substring and then trimming the results for each column with string.Trim.

Comment: It appears to be fixed-width length. How can I trim this text? Can You develop your idea?

Answer (score 0):

Is it a CSV File - are all Fields delimeted with ",". If so do yourself a favor and do not attempt to parse the csv on your own - doing it right can be quite tricky.
I had greadt sucess with KBCSV a free C# library which can read csv files into datatables easily.

Comment: Correct file is a csv, but wrongly formated file, does not contain commas, only spaces between and I want to handle this wrongly formated one.